# Photoshop tvOS LSR extension gives error

Tags: icons, photoshop, tvos

We're trying to create a tvOS application icon for our new tvOS application. We've downloaded the necessary extensions and the example `.psd`. We've tried to generate a preview using the plugin but it keeps saying it's missing a background layer.

I've added the layer, named it background, and locked it, but the same error keeps popping up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the photoshop plugin, but what it probably means is that at least one layer has to be the right size (e.g. 400x240) and has to be opaque.

Also, for what it is worth, you don't need to create a separate layered image unless the layers are of a different size.  You can just drag the individual layers directly into the assets.

Comment: Thanks mike, we've filled layer0 with a color and everything worked as expected...